# Upgrade version of PHPMyAdmin

Tags: phpmyadmin, mamp

I'd like to match locally the same version of phpmyadmin installed in my production server. 
Is there a way to upgrade the version of Phpmyadmin in MAMP to the last version without breaking it?

I upgraded MAMP but the latest version do not include the updated PhpMyAdmin, just an old version.

Comment: Have you tried to download the latest version and replace the one in the subfolder of MAMP?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Download the latest version from [here](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/downloads.php).

Find and replace `Applications/MAMP/bin/phpMyAdmin` ( MAMP local folder directory) with the latest phpMyAdmin you downloaded.

Don't change the folder name (keep the folder name on "phpMyAdmin").

Make sure you have *config.inc.php* in the /phpMyAdmin folder.  As mentioned below, you can copy that file over from your existing phpMyAdmin folder.

Comment: it worked! My folder was named just "phpMyAdmin". Very easy, thanks.

Comment: I tried upgrading the version by replacing the folder but it didn't work. Well it did but it had be login but before it didn't. Does this mean there is a problem? I don't know the username/pass to my phpMyAdmin, where could I find it? In **httpd.conf**? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Nathan the default user/pass for mamp is root/root - worked for me.

Comment: @Reuben Yeah, I've known that for a while now, I Google'd it a while back. :) But thanks for replying to my comment!

Comment: I'm using MAMP and renamed Applications/MAMP/bin/phpMyAdmin to Applications/MAMP/bin/phpMyAdminOLD. I copied phpMyAdmin4.0.6 all languages directory to Applications/MAMP/bin/phpMyAdmin and restarted the MAMP services.  Nothing happens when I click on the phpMyAdmin link in the MAMP Start Page.

Comment: I copied the previous config.inc.php file to the 4.0.6 folder and it worked and gives me message Unknown language: en-iso-8859-1, which this post addresses http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16451637/mamp-pro-updating-myphpadmin-issue

Comment: Mine was located in "Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO/bin/phpMyAdmin" for some reason.

Comment: I have updated it successfully. It asks for login username and password and we can enter 'root' as username and password. Thanks Wei Lu. Happy to get your help :)

Comment: Actually (2023), I have 2 folders in the `bin` folder: `phpMyAdmin` and `phpMyAdmin5`. Are they totally different? I also have 2 other folders: `phpLiteAdmin` and `phpPgAdmin`. So I guess that `phpMyAdmin5 `is the last version. Am I right? Then, should I also update the other folders or they will be replaced or modified automatically?

Comment: It worked for me I renamed phpMyAdmin5 to phpMyAdmin5OLD and renamed the downloaded folder as phpMyAdmin5

Answer (score 22):

If you have MAMP PRO replace the /phpMyAdmin installation folder in the following folder:
/Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO/

Answer (score 18):

I had the same problem as @Nathan and followed these steps to get the latest phpMyAdmin working. [@thanaxix gave a valuable insight and the steps have been refined here]

1. Get the latest [phpMyAdmin](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/downloads.php)
2. Copy the `config.inc.php` file from `/Applications/MAMP/bin/phpMyAdmin` to the desktop.
3. Delete the `phpMyAdmin` folder from `/Applications/MAMP/bin/phpMyAdmin`
4. Unzip the phpMyAdmin file you downloaded, rename the resulting folder to `phpMyAdmin` [syntax is important here] and copy it to `/Applications/MAMP/bin/`
5. Copy the `config.inc.php` file from your desktop to `/Applications/MAMP/bin/phpMyAdmin`. 6.  I would suggest you make one edit to `config.inc.php`. On line 61 you will need to add a blowfish secret in between the single quotes:

   ```
   $cfg['blowfish_secret'] = '';
   ```
6. Start up MAMP Pro and when you choose the phpMyAdmin tab you should be directed to your updated phpMyAdmin.

Hope this helps.

Comment: +1 because this is the best laid out answer but I wouldn't suggest they delete the old PhpMyAdmin. Just rename it and then they can just drag the old `config.inc.php` and skip steps 1,2 and 5.

Answer (score 1):

first remove older version:

```
sudo apt-get remove phpmyadmin

sudo apt-get purge phpmyadmin
```

and type:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nijel/phpmyadmin
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin
```

Answer (score 1):

For Windows 10 users with MAMP PRO installed phpMyAdmin is not loaded from the default `MAMP/bin/phpMyAdmin` folder.

- Download the phpMyAdmin version you want
- Navigate to `C:\Users\Public\Documents\Appsolute\MAMPPRO`
- rename `phpmyadmin` to `phpmyadmin_old`
- copy the newly downloaded phpMyAdmin here and rename the folder to `phpmyadmin` note that it's all lowercase here
- Copy `config.inc.php` from `phpmyadmin_old` to `phpmyadmin`
- Restart MAMP services

Answer (score 1):

If you use the MAMP Pro version, Directory is `/Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO`

for macOS
`cd /Library/Application\ Support/appsolute/MAMP\ PRO`

Download the latest & parse folder then copy `config.inc.php` to the latest folder

Last step open `config.inc.php` edit line 60 `$cfg['blowfish_secret'] = ''` You need generate a random string 32 length to this line, this use of phpMyAdmin.

Restart MAMP Service.

Comment: This solved it for me, thanks. For some reason there were two PMA folders in the /Applications/MAMP/bin folder too, but they seem to be unused.

Also note that there's an appsolute/MAMP\ PRO folder in the user library too but the correct one is the root library folder. If you're uncertain how to get there, open Terminal and type "open /Library".

Answer (score 0):

If you have upgraded from MAMP to MAMP Pro, you only have to update the phpMyAdmin folder in 
"Applications/MAMP/bin/phpMyAdmin", even though the /Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO/ exists. As mentioned before, keep the config.inc.php file and copy it back inside the folder.

Comment: You can use `backticks` to help format your answer better. Just a suggestion.