# MAMP Pro - updating phpMyAdmin issue

Tags: phpmyadmin, mamp

I am having an issue after updating my MAMP Pro to the latest phpMyAdmin (4.0.0). The error is:

```
Unknown language: en-iso-8859-1.
```

How do I resolve this? I attempted to edit `config.inc.php` by removing the `en-` part of the language and charset conversion settings. I have edited both `config.inc.php` files in `Applications/MAMP/bin/phpMyAdmin`, and `/Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO/` directories. I am still encountering the issue. What else do I need to check?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem when I upgraded phpMyAdmin. Take a look here `Applications/MAMP/bin/phpMyAdmin/locale` and see if there is a folder named `en` and I suspect there won't be. It turns out that when I downloaded the update it was the British English version and the folder was named `en_GB` which I believe is the reason for the error `Unknown language: en-iso-8859-1` but I do not know for sure.

My solution was to change the `config.inc.php` file to this:

`$cfg['DefaultLang'] = 'en_GB-iso-8859-1';`

Previously it was *$cfg['DefaultLang'] = 'en-iso-8859-1';*

I no longer have this error message for phpMyAdmin on MAMP 2.1.3. Hope this helps.

Comment: Also, this seems silly but it's possible to set the language via a URL parameter. My phpMyAdmin bookmark had a URL parameter setting the language, so no matter how many places I changed the language in the config files I still saw that error message until I removed the language from the URL.

Answer (score 5):

I think that is a partial answer. I had to go to /Applications/MAMP/bin/mamp/English
and fix the files index.php and navigation.php. I replaced en-iso-8859-1 with en and everything is fine now. I also had to remember to copy the config.inc.php from the previous versions directory and I made the change recommended above. I changed the language in config.inc.php to en.

```
$cfg['DefaultLang'] = 'en';
```

In summary, it works now and I do not get that annoying error message. If only I can remember to make these changes on the other systems in the office. That is why I am documenting it here. Sort of an external memory.

Answer (score 0):

My solution:
- follow exactly the instructions in here:

[Upgrading phpmyadmin](http://blog-en.mamp.info/2013/08/how-to-upgrade-phpmyadmin-in-mamp-mamp.html)
and delete any phpmyadmin-OLD folders

- @ Applications/MAMP/bin/phpMyAdmin/locale I create an empty folder named "en"
- @ config.inc.php, I uncommented the line:

  // Force: always use this language - must be defined in
  //        libraries/select_lang.lib.php
  //uncommented the next line to force en language
  $cfg['Lang'] = 'en-iso-8859-1';

  - VERY IMPORTANT: restart the server, clean brownser cache !

Answer (score 0):

To recap and add additional info, you have to follow both of previous replies:

1) Go to Applications/MAMP/bin/phpMyAdmin/locale and change the config.inc.php file to this:

$cfg['DefaultLang'] = 'en_GB-iso-8859-1';

2) Go to /Applications/MAMP/bin/mamp/English and fix the files index.php and navigation.php. 
Replace en-iso-8859-1 with en-GB-iso-8859-1.

Last, go to /library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO/mamp/English and do the same for index.php and navigation.php